# Making UITableViewIndexSearch jump to tableHeaderView instead of section 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have my table view's search bar as its `tableHeaderView` (mainly because it keeps keyboard focus even when calling `reloadData`).

I also have my right-edge alphabetic index list, with the amazing `UITableViewIndexSearch` denoting the magnifying glass icon on top of it. But `sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` will only allow mapping it to section index `0`, which autoscrolls to the table view's first section (but leaves my search field hidden above it). What is the most elegant way to reveal the whole `tableHeaderView` whenever the index's magnifying glass icon is tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I can make this happen by dispatching a very slightly (0.01 seconds) delayed `tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero` before I return the zero from `sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`. This is rather fishy, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

From Matt Neuberg's book "Programming iOS 7", I found this rather usefull trick:

When a user taps on the magnifying glass (index 0), it scrolls the header into view, and we'll return a fake section number.

Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
       sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
                           atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    if(index == 0){
        tableView.scrollRectToVisible((tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame)!, animated: false)
    }
    return index-1
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) 
       sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title
                           atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if(index == 0)
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:tableView.tableHeaderView.frame animated: NO];

    return index-1;
}
```